# How can I create a Contacts Group from 8,000+ emails without having to type them all in?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have received thousands of emails for a proposed project.  I need to respond to all of those emails in one email.  How can I quickly create a contacts group without having to type each one of these email addresses in?

Comment: where do you have those 8000+ email contacts? excel? spreadsheet?

Comment: It's not possible to send a email a large number of contacts by using a contacts group. If you are still interested on on this question and would like further help, please edit the question to add more details including a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have to [build a CSV file](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/04/24/convert-excel-csv/) with all the emails (or names/emails) and [import it](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/1069522?hl=en&visit_id=636701742289416395-1019709718&rd=1) via contacts manager.

If viewing the contacts inside Gmail (`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts`):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[image]

If viewing the contacts site (`https://contacts.google.com/`):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[image]

I exported a CSV from Gmail and the format it expects is a whooping number of 88 fields, you just need **`E-mail Address`** all the other 87 can be left blank:

> First Name,Middle Name,Last Name,Title,Suffix,Initials,Web Page,Gender,Birthday,Anniversary,Location,Language,Internet Free Busy,Notes,E-mail Address,E-mail 2 Address,E-mail 3 Address,Primary Phone,Home Phone,Home Phone 2,Mobile Phone,Pager,Home Fax,Home Address,Home Street,Home Street 2,Home Street 3,Home Address PO Box,Home City,Home State,Home Postal Code,Home Country,Spouse,Children,Manager's Name,Assistant's Name,Referred By,Company Main Phone,Business Phone,Business Phone 2,Business Fax,Assistant's Phone,Company,Job Title,Department,Office Location,Organizational ID Number,Profession,Account,Business Address,Business Street,Business Street 2,Business Street 3,Business Address PO Box,Business City,Business State,Business Postal Code,Business Country,Other Phone,Other Fax,Other Address,Other Street,Other Street 2,Other Street 3,Other Address PO Box,Other City,Other State,Other Postal Code,Other Country,Callback,Car Phone,ISDN,Radio Phone,TTY/TDD Phone,Telex,User 1,User 2,User 3,User 4,Keywords,Mileage,Hobby,Billing Information,Directory Server,Sensitivity,Priority,Private,Categories

Also note that Google can't import more than 3,000 contacts at once (split them in various CSVs), and the total limit of contacts is 25,000.

Comment: ps: I didn't test creating a CSV with just a few header fields (like name, last name, email) to see Google can import it